# nav2d autonomouse exploration

Tags: ros, exploration, nav2d-exploration, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed and tried nav2d navigation package exploration feature, with a real robot setup (kobuki base, urg-04lx) as per ros wiki instructions. i modified the tutorial3 launch and param files, as shown below (just copied the launch file and .yaml files into my catkin workspace so i can edit them).
I received a map and other topics in RVIZ. since i dont have a joy stick i used `rosservice call /StartMapping 3` and `rosservice call /StartExploration 2` as per tutorials instructions i got nothing but a "response: 0" on my terminal window.

LAUNCH File:

```
<launch>

<!-- Some general parameters -->
<param name="use_sim_time" value="false" />
<rosparam file="$(find navigation)/param/ros.yaml"/>

<!-- Start Stage simulator with a given environment
<node name="Stage" pkg="stage_ros" type="stageros" args="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/world/tutorial.world">
    <param name="base_watchdog_timeout" value="0" />
</node> -->

<!-- Start the Operator to control the simulated robot -->
<node name="Operator" pkg="nav2d_operator" type="operator" >
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation)/param/operator.yaml"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation)/param/costmap.yaml" ns="local_map" />
</node>

<!-- Start Mapper to genreate map from laser scans -->
<node name="Mapper" pkg="nav2d_karto" type="mapper">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation)/param/mapper.yaml"/>
</node>

<!-- Start the Navigator to move the robot autonomously -->
<node name="Navigator" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="navigator">
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation)/param/navigator.yaml"/>
            <!-- <remap from="/cmd_vel" to="/mobile_base/commands/velocity" /> -->
</node>

<node name="GetMap" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="get_map_client" />
<node name="Explore" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="explore_client" />
<node name="SetGoal" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="set_goal_client" />

<!-- Start particle filter to track the robot's position 
<node name="SelfLocalizer" pkg="nav2d_localizer" type="localizer">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
    <param name="min_particles" type="int" value="5000"/>
    <param name="max_particles" type="int" value="20000"/>
</node> -->

<!-- Start the joystick-driver and remote-controller for operation
<node name="Joystick" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" />
<node name="Remote" pkg="nav2d_remote" type="remote_joy" /> -->

<!-- RVIZ to view the visualization -->
<node name="RVIZ" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args=" -d $(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/tutorial3.rviz" />
```

when i tried to launch the SelfLocalizer in my launch file, it gave me an error saying: `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nav2d_localizer/localizer]: can't locate node [localizer] in package [nav2d_localizer]`

Another issue, i tried to remap `/cmd_vel` to kobuki's velocity topic but i received an error, [MD5] topic format mismatch.

any help, suggestions are greately appreciated. Param files (.yaml) are also available.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the [rqt_dot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r12e3ocky6nxv6h/nav2d_rqtgraph.dot?dl=0) file to download.

tf_tree:

[image: tf_tree]

rqt_graph:

[image: rqt_graph]

it also takes like 20 seconds or so before the topics in RVIZ receive information and go green.

**UPDATE 2:**
Parameters list:
PARAMETERS

```
 * /Mapper/LoopSearchMaximumDistance: 10.0
 * /Mapper/MinimumTravelDistance: 1.0
 * /Mapper/MinimumTravelHeading: 0.52
 * /Mapper/grid_resolution: 0.05
 * /Mapper/map_update_rate: 5
 * /Mapper/max_covariance: 0.01
 * /Mapper/max_particles: 10000
 * /Mapper/min_map_size: 20
 * /Mapper/min_particles: 2500
 * /Mapper/publish_pose_graph: True
 * /Mapper/range_threshold: 4.0
 * /Mapper/transform_publish_period: 0.1
 * /Navigator/exploration_goal_distance: 0.5
 * /Navigator/map_inflation_radius: 0.25
 * /Navigator/min_target_area_size: 1.0
 * /Navigator/navigation_goal_angle: 1.0
 * /Navigator/navigation_goal_distance: 0.5
 * /Navigator/navigation_homing_distance: 0.5
 * /Navigator/robot_radius: 0.2
 * /Navigator/visualize_frontiers: True
 * /Operator/conformance_weight: 1
 * /Operator/continue_weight: 0
 * /Operator/distance_weight: 1
 * /Operator/local_map/cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
 * /Operator/local_map/footprint: [[-0.18, -0.18], ...
 * /Operator/local_map/global_frame: odom
 * /Operator/local_map/height: 10.0
 * /Operator/local_map/inflation_radius: 0.25
 * /Operator/local_map/lethal_cost_threshold: 100
 * /Operator/local_map/map_type: costmap
 * /Operator/local_map/max_obstacle_height: 0.5
 * /Operator/local_map/min_obstacle_height: 0.0
 * /Operator/local_map/observation_sources: laser
 * /Operator/local_map/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /Operator/local_map/publish_frequency: 3.0
 * /Operator/local_map/publish_voxel_map: False
 * /Operator/local_map/raytrace_range: 4.5
 * /Operator/local_map/resolution: 0.05
 * /Operator/local_map/robot_base_frame: base_footprint
 * /Operator/local_map/robot_radius: 0.2
 * /Operator/local_map/rolling_window: True
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/clearing: True
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/data_type: LaserScan
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/expected_update_rate: 0.4
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/marking: True
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/max_obstacle_height: 0.4
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/min_obstacle_height: 0.08
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/observation_persistence: 0.0
 * /Operator/local_map/scan/topic: base_scan
 * /Operator/local_map/static_map: False
 * /Operator/local_map/track_unknown_space: True
 * /Operator/local_map/transform_tolerance: 0.3
 * /Operator/local_map/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /Operator/local_map/width: 10.0
 * /Operator/max_free_space: 1.0
 * /Operator/max_velocity: 0.1
 * /Operator/publish_route: True
 * /Operator/safety_decay: 0.97
 * /Operator/safety_weight: 2
 * /SelfLocalizer/max_particles: 20000
 * /SelfLocalizer/min_particles: 5000
 * /laser_frame: laser
 * /laser_topic: base_scan
 * /map_frame: map
 * /map_service: static_map
 * /map_topic: map
 * /odometry_frame: odom
 * /offset_frame: offset
 * /robot_frame: base_footprint
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.10
 * /use_sim_time: Fals
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209177/nav2d-autonomouse-exploration/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-15**:
@sobot Please add a picture from "rqt_graph" and the dot-export result from "rosrun tf view_frames". These are usually the best starting point to search for problems in your setup.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-15**:
@Sebastian Kasperski really appreciate it, i updated the question with the info that you asked.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-17**:
The transformations look fine, but in your ROS-Graph you see that the Operator in not connected to "base_scan". As the remapping is correct, it probably doesn't get to the point where the Costmap is initialized. Does it give any warnings or errors during start?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-17**:
@Sebastian Kasperski i only can get 2 errors in different start up setups: (1. when i try to remap /cmd_vel to topic of my robot. (it says content is mismatch, MD5 xxx) (2. when i include SelfLocalizer in the launch file, its says the node can not be found int the package folder.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-18**:
@sobot: 1) Please do a "rostopic type" on your robots cmd-topic. If its not geometry_msgs/Twist, you have to do a conversion. 2) Have you build the package from source or installed the binary packages?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-18**:
@Sebastian Kasperski the topic is **/mobile_base/commands/velocity** and rostopic shows that type is geometry_msgs/Twist. tried to remap that topic to /cmd_vel and got the MD5 error. I installed the pkg from the binary as per in the ros-wiki instructions using apt-get install.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-19**:
@sobot: This is really strange. Do you have different ROS-Versions on your machine? Or does any of your packages bring an own version of "geometry_msgs"? Before you start your launch file, do a "roscd geometry_msgs" and check where it takes you.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-19**:
My machine's config is: native "Ubuntu 14,04" with ROS Indigo (full desktop). i just use this 1 machine, and it runs my robot. roscd takes me to **/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometry_msgs$**
yes it looks very strange. i thought it should be pretty straightforward. other packages work Ok.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-20**:
Sometimes one misses messages from startup when launching rqt_console after the launch file. Can you add an output="screen" to the Operator's node-tag in your launch file and see if anything else pops up during startup? Have you build the kobuki base package on this machine or is it also a binary?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-20**:
yes, i installed Kobuki from binary. added the output=screen and received the following warning repeatedly on screen. ( [ WARN] [1432152439.052146627]: Robot is stuck! Trying to recover... ). Around the robot is all open wide. i also UPDATED question with parameters list.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-21**:
"Robot is stuck" can happen at the beginning, but if this warning is there, then the Operator completed its startup. So the real problem seems to be the not-connected /cmd_vel topic. Can you make the kobuki move manually? (http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Examine%20Kobuki#Trigger_stuff)

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-21**:
@Sebastian Kasperski Yes Kobuki moves manually (keyop), also through rviz set goal and some other nodes that i tried out.
still Localisation node gives error (can not find node) and don't start. also "Robot is stuck" repeats over and over again until i abort the launch.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-21**:
Yes, the "Robot is stuck" warning is ok for now. But can you move the robot as it is described in the link, by using "rostopic pub"? Have you installed ros-indigo-nav2d_localizer package? It contains the localizer node. (But you don't need it for mapping/exploration anyway)

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-21**:
yes `rostopic pub` in the link works. i installed nav2d using the `install ros-indigo-nav2d` line, didn't install localizer separately, sorry! are there different versions of nav2d available so i test? what minimums i need for autonomous exploration launch, so i make a clean launch file to test. THX

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-05-21**:
Your launch-file looks ok, the minimum you need from nav2d is Operator, Navigator and Mapper. The 3 Action-Clients and Joystick are for convinience. Maybe you should try to put kobuki-stuff and nav2d-stuff in one launch file and start this. (and post this file when you have it)

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-21**:
Hi Sebastian, i made some progress, fixed the `cmd_vel` topic mappings successfully, but Explorer don't work yet. I filmed the robot for you to see: i run the launch file and manually set a simple goal, see what happens. also shared the Launch and Param files in dropbox for you ".zip file" (below)

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-21**:
launch, param, new rqt_graph files in a zip file [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z64wkm00q28msev/nav2d_files.zip?dl=0) and the video of the robot shared on youtube [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XmHxIfRHvk) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The operator is not connected to the laser scanner. It needs it to update the local costmap for obstacle avoidance. In your costmap.yaml, the observation_source is defined incorrectly. Should be: "observation_sources: scan". You should visualize the costmap in RVIZ to see if the local costmap (not the global map from the mapper) is built correctly.

Before you start any navigation task (setting a goal via RVIZ or explore) you should move the robot a bit forward, (with a joystick or by calling "rosservice call /StartMapping 3")

In your mapper.yaml you have "range_threshold: 4.0". This is VERY little for a Hokuyo-Scanner! This is the reason your global map is so small and has a lot of holes in it. Use at least 10 meter. (Hokuyo can easily go up to 30 meter)

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-22**:
Changed `observation_sources` and ran a quick test and it worked...! my Hokuyo scanner is URG-04LX-UG01 and according to its data sheet Max range is 4m , so the only way to increase maps size is to increase the `range_threshold`? **You are awesome! thanks for your time, really appreciate it..!**